How to allow public access (without authentication) to an api with jhipster 8.4.0
I'm using jhipster 8.4.0 in an angular project
I want the application to provide the user entered during registration on the user registration screen as a parameter to an API that searches for the account by the user and found, returns the account activation status (true/false).
ignoring the flow, the problem is... logged into the application, the service works normally through swagger and returns what is expected, but through postman when I perform my tests, it only works if I provide a bearer token, but I need the api to be able to consumed by unauthenticated users and not just authenticated ones.
.authorizeHttpRequests(
                authz ->
                    // prettier-ignore
                authz
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/account/activated/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/account/activated/{login}")).permitAll()

Likewise, in my AccountResource.java I inserted the @PermitAll annotation:
    @PermitAll
    @GetMapping("/account/activated/{login}")
    public boolean getActivationStatusByLogin(@PathVariable String login) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(login);
        return user.map(User::isActivated).orElseThrow(() -> new AccountResourceException("User with login " + login + " not found"));
    }

remembering that the postman get I perform through the url
http://localhost:8080/api/account/activated/string-do-login-consultado
It turns out that there is nothing else to do, I only receive the status 401 - Unauthorized.
Postman for example, if I add the bearer token, it works exactly the same as when I'm logged in and I test the api using the application's swagger.
What else do I need to do to make this service public, I've already tested everything I know, so wise wizards of the dev world, help this grasshopper here, please.

Spring Security 5 allowed unspecified paths by default whereas Spring Security 6 denies unspecified paths by default. If you create a new FooController that's mapped to /foo, you have to allow it in SpaWebFilter and SecurityConfiguration. For example:
package com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s", name != null ? name : "World");
    }
}

SpaWebFilter.java:
public class SpaWebFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    /**
     * Forwards any unmapped paths (except those containing a period) to the client {@code index.html}.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Request URI includes the contextPath if any, removed it.
        String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
        if (
            !path.startsWith("/foo") &&
            !path.startsWith("/api") &&
            !path.startsWith("/management") &&
            !path.startsWith("/v3/api-docs") &&
            !path.contains(".") &&
            path.matches("/(.*)")
        ) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

SecurityConfiguration.java:
.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/foo")).permitAll()

If you want to use @PermitAll(), you have to add jsr250Enabled = true to @EnableMethodSecurity. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#use-jsr250 for more information.
